# Javascript Возможно ли такое сравнение

Tags: javascript

```
  if (s1.innerHTML == s4.innerHTML == s7.innerHTML == "X" || s1.innerHTML ==       s4.innerHTML == s7.innerHTML == "O") return true;
```

Comment: Почему такой вопрос? Что мешает взять и проверить?

Comment: по логике должно работать, а на деле не работает , хотел уточнить (хотя да в простом коде можно было протестировать)

Comment: @Тигран, ни по какой логике это выражение работать не должно.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Да, формально такое сравнение возможно.

---

Не смотря на это, оно **лишено смысла**. В этом легко убедиться, разобравшись как именно вычисляется значение выражения в операторе `if`.

Оператор равенства имеет [левую ассоциативность](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table). Это значит, что выражение

```
a == b == c
```

будет преобразовано интерпретатором в

```
(a == b) == c
```

Первая часть вашего выражения (до оператора `||`) будет эквивалентна выражению:

```
(((s1.innerHTML == s4.innerHTML) == s7.innerHTML) == "X")
```

Обратите внимание, первое и второе равенство вернут либо `true` либо `false`. При этом, ни одно из этих значений не будет равно `"X"`. Иными словами, все выражение будет равно `false`.

Аналогично, вторая часть выражения будет эквивалентна:

```
(((s1.innerHTML == s4.innerHTML) == s7.innerHTML) == "O")
```

что тоже будет равно `false` при любых значениях `s1`, `s4`, `s7`.

Ну и напоследок, все ваше условие можно записать как:

```
(((s1.innerHTML == s4.innerHTML) == s7.innerHTML) == "X")
    || (((s1.innerHTML == s4.innerHTML) == s7.innerHTML) == "O")
```

Или, с учетом приведенных выше выкладок:

```
false || false
```

что, разумеется, тождественно равно `false` при любых значениях.

**UPD:**

Если есть желание убедиться, что я говорю правду, можете выполнить элементарный тест:

```
console.log("X" == "X" == "X" == "X"); // false
```

Comment: как бы и понятно и не понятно ,понятно что так должно было быть если не одно обстоятельство , это же "if" здесь должен был просто сравнить значение (я так думаю , и сразу ответ на верхний коментарий- вот из за таких нюансов не был уверен что всё так как я пологаю ),,, а как мне быть в таком случае ?  наверняка понятно что мне хочется сделать

Comment: и верю и вижу - у меня не работает код

Comment: `if` выполняет либо один блок кода либо другой в зависимости от **значения логического выражения** которое вы туда передаете. Как вычисляется выражение я уже описал. Весь ваш код, тождественно равен `if (false) return true;`

Comment: @Тигран, код у вас работает, причем именно так, как и должен. JavaScript не виноват, что вы _ожидаете_ других результатов

Comment: @DmitriySimushev так , минутку пожалуйста , если написать if(proverka==false ) будет работать код? я щяс проверю , и второй вопрос , как я понял проверка должна быть на подобие этой  ?

Comment: if (cell[0] == cell[1] && cell[2] == 0 && cell[0] == i) PutHere = 2;

Comment: @Тигран, да, вполне

Comment: спасибо большое , у меня не сработало я поэтому спрашивал, хоть так то буду знать что в коде у меня проблемы а так всё правильно